# How to retrieve Serial Number from Windows on new U/EFI box?

Tags: windows, wmi, uefi

I need to retrieve the hardware serial numbers from a set of new HP mini desktops that need provisioning.

This worked in the past using a WSH script to query it via WMI.  Unfortunately, the newer models no longer contain a BIOS but rather come with EFI instead.  All known ways of querying the information no longer work.

I've googled the subject quite a bit but all the answers I found recommend the ineffective method above.  Can anyone help?  I need a solution that will work with XP (embedded) if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out the model we had was a pre-release box, and a serial number hadn't been assigned yet.  Once trying it on a newer box, it worked just fine.  The value was available via WMI after all.

Nothing to see here, move along.  ;)

Scripting examples in the language of your choice to print serial numbers can be found at [Microsoft TechNet](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=hardware&f%5B0%5D.Text=Hardware&f%5B1%5D.Type=SubCategory&f%5B1%5D.Value=basichardware&f%5B1%5D.Text=Basic%20Hardware%20and%20Firmware).

Comment: Can you post the actual command used to retrieve the serial number to assist future visitors?

Answer (score 3):

dmidecode in linux is capable of pulling this information via EFI, there is a port available here http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/dmidecode.htm which appears to be compiled after EFI support. The command would dmidecode -s system-serial-number as tested on my BIOS based system, however I'm unable to test fully as I havn't got an EFI system to hand.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  Unfortunately the need was for Windows.

Comment: There are other programs available for Windows that read the information out of the DMI table - this is a valid answer.

Comment: This is a port to windows, tested on windows 7. The link is for a windows executable.

Answer (score 0):

Scriptomatic 2 (available free from Microsoft) allows you to easily browse all of WMI and provides you with the scripts needed to do so.